# How to target elements that only contains a space(&nbsp;) with CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors, spaces

I'm having a table and there are some columns with the following code:

```
<td class="t-Report-cell" align="right" headers="KORTING_PERC">&nbsp;</td>
```

I would like to be able to target the TD's who are having the headers="KORTING_PERC" and contains only the html variant of a space.

I've tried the following:

```
td[headers="KORTING_PERC"]:contains("&nbsp;")
td[headers="KORTING_PERC"]:contains(" ")
td[headers="KORTING_PERC"]:not(:empty)
```

Using the following with a red background:

```
[headers="KORTING_PERC"]:not(:contains(" ")){
  background: red;
}
```

Results in:

[image: Result]

Comment: 'Contains' doesn't exists in css.. Always try to code in english and don't give your variables dutch names.

Comment: Your table is populated via a script, probably? Then give the table cells a new class whenever they are filled with just a &nbsp;

Answer (score 0):

```css
div[headers='KORTING_PERC'][data-value='23'] {
   background-color: red;
}
```

```html
     <div class="t-Report-cell" align="right" data-value="23" headers="KORTING_PERC">23</div>
     <div class="t-Report-cell" align="right" data-value="" headers="KORTING_PERC">23</div>
```

You can't select by `innerText` using CSS you can use jQuery to select by text or you can add another attribute to the html tag which includes the value of the element and select by that in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a draft for :blank, but it did not made its way to browser implementations.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/b/blank/

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$('td[headers="KORTING_PERC"]').each(function(){
   if($(this).text() == '&nbsp;' || $(this).text() == ''){
      $(this).css('background','red');
   }
});
```